# Combining @Provides and @Inject

Tags: guice

I've recently come across some code that uses both `@Provides` and `@Inject` annotations on the same method. This method has two non-primitive parameters and a non-void return type.

I was wondering whether it made sense to use these two in tandem. From what I can gather/speculate, it seems like `@Inject` is being used to construct the method dependencies using Guice, whereas `@Provides` is being used to bind the return type. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, there is never a case where you'd see [`@Provides`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Provides.html) and [`@Inject`](http://javax-inject.github.io/javax-inject/api/javax/inject/Inject.html) on the same method.

[`@Inject`](http://javax-inject.github.io/javax-inject/api/javax/inject/Inject.html) makes sense on *constructors, methods, and fields*:

- On constructors, it marks the constructor that the DI framework should call. The framework provides all parameter values. This is often called *constructor injection*.
- On fields, it indicates that the DI framework should set the field from outside. The framework provides the field value. This is often called *field injection*.
- On methods, it indicates that after construction the DI framework should call the method *exactly once*. The framework provides the parameter values. The return value is meaningless and often `void`. This is often called *method injection*.

For example:

```java
public class YourInjectableClass {

  // Guice will use this constructor...
  @Inject public YourInjectableClass(YourDep dep) { /* ... */ }
  // ...instead of this one
  public YourInjectableClass(YourDep dep, YourOtherDep otherDep) { /* ... */ }

  // Guice will populate this field after construction.
  @Inject YourField yourField;

  @Inject public void register(Registry registry) {
    // Guice will create or get a Registry and call this method after
    // construction. It sometimes makes sense for this to be protected
    // or package-private so this class's consumers aren't tempted
    // to call it themselves.
  }
}
```

[`@Provides`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Provides.html) has a much narrower purpose: When used in Guice modules, `@Provides` goes on methods and indicates that Guice should call the method whenever it needs an instance of the method's possibly-parameterized type (and inheriting the binding annotations or qualifiers from the method itself). Dagger has [a similar `@Provides` annotation](https://dagger.dev/api/latest/dagger/Provides.html), as `@Provides` isn't defined in the JSR-330 dependency injection standard.

For both Guice and Dagger, the framework will supply the `@Provides` method's parameters whenever the method is called, and without using `@Inject`. The semantics of `@Inject` wouldn't make sense anyway, since even though the parameters are supplied in a similar way to method injection above, the framework may call the `@Provides` method repeatedly but `@Inject` methods are called exactly once.

```java
public class YourModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override public void configure() {)  // still needed for AbstractModule

  // Guice will call this whenever it needs a
  // @SomeBindingAnnotation YourInstance. Because you list a YourDep as a
  // parameter, Guice will get and pass in a YourDep.
  @Provides @SomeBindingAnnotation YourInstance create(YourDep dep) {
    return YourInstanceFactory.create(dep);
  }
}
```

Consequently, *you should almost never see those annotations in the same file*, let alone on the same method. The only exception is if you follow the questionable practice of making a Module that is itself injectable (presumably getting an injected Module from one injector in order to configure a different injector), and even then you wouldn't see them on the same method: `@Inject` methods are called once to store dependencies, and `@Provides` methods should be called whenever a new instance is needed.

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifying. So just to be clear, the methods annotated with @Inject are called after construction of YourInjectableClass then right?

Comment: @OrangeApple3 Yes. That technique is called [method injection](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#method-injection).